# SQL Server Unpivot the data by mapping the columns as Key Value pairs

Tags: sql, sql-server, unpivot

I have a requirement to map the values from two columns to map the values-

Screenshot of the Original Data that needs to be done UnPivot:
[image]

Example-

```
S1 S1Date
S2 S2Date
S3 S3Date
S4 S4Date
```

Data-

```
Cricket      2018-04-07 20:45:22.387
FootBall     2018-04-08 20:45:22.387
TableTennis  2018-04-09 20:45:22.387
Badminton    2018-04-10 20:45:22.387
```

I tried unpivot and was not sure how to map multiple columns. Please assist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do this using `apply`:

```
select v.*
from t cross apply
     (values (s1, s1date), (s2, s2date), (s3, s3date), (s4, s4date)) v(col, dte);
```

`unpivot` does a very specific thing -- I don't think it is even worth learning the syntax.  On the other hand, `apply` is an introduction to lateral joins, which are very powerful.  Unpivot is a good way to start learning about them.